# Read timestamp field and print as 12 December 2017 2:34:23

Tags: flutter, timestamp

Initially, I had used string format for the field `timestamp` and I was able to convert it to  `12 December 2017 2:34:23` format using `toData().toString()`. I need to do the same thing when the field `timestamp` is in `timestamp` format. Can I get some help on this?

Comment: The question is not that clear, are you trying to format a `timestamp` to string and display in the above mentioned format?

Comment: if its epoch time then you can do DateTime.fromMilliSecondsfromEpoch(timestamp)...and then use DateFormat('dd MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss a').parse(date)

Comment: I am trying to convert the `timestamp` field to `12 December 2017 2:34:23 ` format. When the field is in `timestamp` format, how do I convert it to the said format?

Comment: You want to convert it without changing it to `string`? As in converting the `timestamp` itself to a different format?

Answer (score 1):

You can get a DateTime variable from a timestamp using

```
var date = new DateTime.fromMicrosecondsSinceEpoch(timestamp);
```

Once you have your date you can format however you want using a DateFormat for example:

```
  var formatter = new DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd'); // You can change the format here
  String formatted = formatter.format(date);
  print(formatted); // Something like 2019-04-20
```

Answer (score 1):

just check out this example below :

```
var timestamp =1583772663;
       var format = new DateFormat('dd MMMM yyyy, hh:mm:ss');
      var date = new DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(timestamp * 1000);
      var value = format.format(date);
      print(value);
      //output : 09 March 2020, 10:21:03
```

let me know if it works.